# Flutter dual sim -Send SMS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a dual sim android phone. I want to send SMS by selecting sim slots through flutter dart programatically. When i tried , by default , it is going from first sim slot. Is there any solution in flutter , as like in subscriptionManager() in android.

Comment: you can create a native method and the connect it with the flutter with the help of platform channels.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any plugin like subscriptionManager() like Android .

Comment: I don't know about that but as far as I know, flutter does not support core features like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below code in android native and then bridge to Flutter with platform channels.And it worked for me.

```
      SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
      
        if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
            List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(simSlot);
         
            SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(simInfo.getSubscriptionId()).sendTextMessage(phone, null, smsContent, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }else{
            List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(simSlot);
           
            sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
           
            sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, smsContent, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }
```

Comment: Get i read incoming sms in dual sim using flutter?